# My program keeps running a certain input incorrectly. What is wrong with this?

Tags: java

My code is this:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type in your order(ex.5 7 4 6 8 3 9 2 0 1 - SPACES REQUIRED): ");
    String input=sc.nextLine();
    String[] b=input.split(" ");
    sc.close();
    boolean isMixed=false;
     for(int i=0; i < input.length()/2; i++) {
         if(Integer.parseInt(b[i]) < Integer.parseInt(b[i+1])) { // Condition of "int input"
        isMixed=false; // What to print when the condition is true
    }
     else // When condition is false 
            isMixed=true;
            // Prints this when the above condition is true
    }
     if(isMixed=false)
        {
             System.out.println("Mixed"); 
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("Ascending"); 
        }
}
```

But when my input is `1 3 2 4 5 6 7 8 9`, it reads, `Ascending`. What can I do to fix this bug? Is there anything I should take away, add, or change?

Comment: `sc.close();` - don't do this.  `if(isMixed=false)` - no this is wrong, it is supposed to compare not assign.  And for **goodness** sake sort out your indentation.  Can not tell from this badly formatted code, but it looks like you are setting the value of `isMixed` for every iteration of your loop, so basically whatever the last iteration gives, is your result.  I do not think this is correct.

Comment: *Please help me ASAP, because this is due in a few days.* - this is not at all relevant

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `if(isMixed=false)` will never work, because you've missed out on `==` instead of `=`. So you're just assigning the value of `false` to isMixed, and false will never execute an if block.
2. `input.length()/2` is a seemingly clever way to get the number of elements in the array, but it will fail you in many cases. Occam's Razor - use `b.length` instead, because it contains the absolute number of elements.
3. About the whole `isMixed = true;` block, think about it like this: you're innocent unless proven guilty. There's no midway. Similarly, if the element at `[i]` is greater than the one at `[i+1]`, isMixed should become `true`. There's no need for a condition where it becomes false again. If any two elements are in a mixed order, then entire input becomes mixed, so you can break out of the loop then.

   ```
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Type in your order(ex.5 7 4 6 8 3 9 2 0 1 - SPACES REQUIRED): ");
   String input=sc.nextLine();
   String[] b=input.split(" ");
   sc.close();
   boolean isMixed=false;
   for(int i=0; i < b.length-1; i++)
   {
       if(Integer.parseInt(b[i]) > Integer.parseInt(b[i+1]))
       {
           isMixed = true;
           break;
       }
       // Prints this when the above condition is true
   }
   if(isMixed==true)
   {
       System.out.println("Mixed"); 
   } else
   {
       System.out.println("Ascending"); 
   }
   ```

   I'll be explaining this soon, but I encourage you to compare this to yours to identify the mistakes you've made.

Comment: @user85421 I'm aware of that, but I decided to keep it, since OP seems familiar with it.

Comment: @user85421 I meant that the OP seems to understand its logic slightly better than `if(booleanValue)`. I was anyway planning on adding that to the list of improvements he can make.

Comment: but...when i put the in (132456789 )it says ascending when its not. i think there's something you overlooked in the code.

Comment: I've tried the program on my pc, and it works correctly. You might have copied the answer wrong.

Comment: a) if `isMixed` then break b) don't close `System.in` c) use `if (isMIxed)`

Comment: @boiyeet *when i put the in (132456789 )* - according to your code, these need to be separated with spaces

Comment: @ScaryWombat Although `if(isMixed)` looks cleaner, the OP isn't too familiar with that syntax yet, so I've chosen to keep it as `if(isMixed == true)` as it's easier to understand.

Comment: @ScaryWombat In school, we use scanner a lot, and it's basically become practice to keep spaces between inputs. So it's understandable how the OP thinks this is common practice.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I agree that the first point is relevant, but from the perspective of someone who's still in school, I feel it's irrelevant to burden him with closing input streams. I highly doubt I would have wanted to learn more about America's agriculture in school any more than necessary and required.

Comment: *I highly doubt I would have wanted to learn more about America's agriculture in school any more than necessary and required* - what on earth are you talking about?

Comment: *@boiyeet when i put the in (132456789 )* - yes if you entered *132456789* without spaces it returns *Ascending* - is this what you are confused about?

Comment: @ScaryWombat OP has clearly mentioned that the input is just numbers separated by spaces. Why would you include parentheses?

Comment: @ScaryWombat What I mean by the agricultural comment is, the OP is relatively new to programming, so I didn't feel it was necessary to burden him with more information than necessary. Although I was taught about agriculture in school, I don't find it easier and relevant to go out of my way to obtain new knowledge about it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat You're definitely more experienced than the OP, but adding irrelevant information is pointless, if there's no warrant for it.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need `isMixed = false` in the if condition. Moreover, you need to iterate over the entire length of the array

Comment: what do you mean, iterate? can u give an example?

Comment: `iterate` is an English word - look it up.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. Was it due to `WordNotFoundInMyDictionaryException`?

Comment: No, it is because your answer was inadequate.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks for your remarks. Will improve on this.